# Testing PowerShell string equality

Tags: string, windows, powershell, equality

I am trying to ascertain whether 2 application version strings are equal in PowerShell and am getting a confusing result:

```
PS C:\> $version = wmic product where "caption like '%Citrix Workspace Inside%'" get Version
PS C:\> $versionString = "22.5.0.4"

PS C:\> $version[2]
22.5.0.4
PS C:\> $versionString
22.5.0.4
PS C:\> $version[2].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object


PS C:\> $versionString.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object


PS C:\> $version[2] -eq $versionString
False
```

Is it something to do with what's returned from the 'wmic' command? The return type of `$version` is `Object[]`, an object array so I've just indexed it to grab the string I need. Both `$version[2]` and `$versionString` have the same value and type but return False when compared for equality. Any light on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Of interest before using win32_product: https://xkln.net/blog/please-stop-using-win32product-to-find-installed-software-alternatives-inside/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, a **warning**:

- The **[`Win32_Product`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa394378(v=vs.85))** WMI class (which the `product` argument in your `wmic` call implicitly refers to) is ***best avoided***, because it returns only Windows Installer-installed applications, is not query-optimized (even when filtering, *all* products must be enumerated), and - most importantly - *invariably performs consistency checks and potentially triggers repair actions*. For background information and an alternative, see [this excellent blog post](https://xkln.net/blog/please-stop-using-win32product-to-find-installed-software-alternatives-inside/).
- The [`WIMC.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic) CLI is *deprecated* in favor of PowerShell's CIM cmdlets (see below).

---

The **only *immediate* problem** with your code is that the version numbers returned have ***trailing spaces***. Therefore:

```
# .Trim() removes leading and trailing whitespace.
$version[2].Trim() -eq $versionString
```

However, its **better to use [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance) to retrieve information from WMI**, as it **returns *objects*** whose *properties* you can access:

```
$version = (
  Get-CimInstance Win32_Product -Filter "caption like '%Citrix Workspace Inside%'"
).Version

$version[0] -eq $versionString
```

Note that `$version[0]`, i.e. the *first* object returned, contains the version number of interest, with **no need to work around formatting artifacts such as trailing spaces, header lines, or empty lines** (as you have to with the *text-only* output from external programs such as `WMIC.exe`).

The fact that `.Version` returns the version numbers of *all* objects returned by the `Get-CimInstance` call is owed to PowerShell's convenient [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) feature.

- As an aside: While you could improve the efficiency of the `Get-CimInstance` call slightly by including `-Property Version`, which only fills in the `.Version` property on the objects returned, you'll still need to use `.Version` afterwards to get the version number.